# iOS JUCE library issue with 64 bit architecture

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, juce

I am working on very old project that has JUCE library with 32 bit architecture. some days ago, I did translated it from 32 bit to 64 bit architecture and problems is occur.
And also JUCE library has C++ code and it's hard to understand why error is occurring.
I am getting below error.

```
Cast from pointer to smaller type 'pointer_sized_int' (aka 'int') loses information
```

At `pointer_sized_int` Variable.

And also I tried to set `long pointer_sized_int` but some other error was occurred.

```
Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'juce::JuceStaticAssert<false>'
```

I mean This library is not compatible with 64 bit Architecture. *(which I'm using)*

Basically I used [**"JUCE Amalgamation"**](https://github.com/vinniefalco/JUCEAmalgam) library in source code in the project and also I find out this library and also include in my project ***(I tried many way to fix it)*** but didn't get success.

Anybody have faced this type of issue before ?
Please suggest me how can I solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are using an old version of JUCE, these issues were fixed some time ago. Please update by going to the [JUCE download page](http://www.juce.com/download) or (recommended) using the latest from [GitHub](https://github.com/julianstorer/juce).

JUCE amalgamation was also deprecated a long time ago and is no longer supported as a consequence; you should start using JUCE modules as soon as possible.

Comment: I know it but there is no any solution for it.